# Create a type with default value and check constraint in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

What's the recommended way to create a type in MSSQL 2005 with a default value and a check constraint to be used in several columns?

I don't want to add a check constraint and a default value for every single column.

My first idea was to create a default and a rule to bind to this type but books online clearly states that we should avoid using CREATE DEFAULT and CREATE RULE for new development because these commands will be removed in a future version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, fine. Mercifully it is still all there is SQL Server 2008. Robyn Page's article on Simple-Talk explains it all

[Robyn Page's SQL Server Data Validation Workbench](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/robyn-pages-sql-server-data-validation-workbench/)

(I have a feeling I helped her a bit with that one) 
Just create a **Type**, and bind defaults and rules to it.

The deprecation issue is a bit of a shame. All that has happened is that **rules**, **types** and **defaults** have fallen foul of the SQL Standard. The preferred way now is to use constraint  to do the same thing, but it is a lot less elegant if you need to do it uniformly in several tables. Also, it is only people like Joe Celko who understand constraints in their entirety. Sure as anything I don't.

Comment: Thanks. That's probably what I'm going to do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can accomplish it with a User Defined Data Type but even then you will have to change the data type for all your columns

Comment: That's what I want to do, a user defined data type. But how? 
It's a new database, so changing data types is not an issue.

Comment: Above link is to Sql Server 2000 documentation. For 2008 see here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189283.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I use CREATE TYPE and CREATE RULE to set default constraints, but not a default value; that's still done at the table level, but there's no good reason why you can't. I also like to use named table-level constraints instead of relying on the system-generated names for the column-level syntax.

I use this template script for my snippet engine; the "~~" are replacement parameter delimiters:

```
IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DOMAINS d
    WHERE
        (d.DOMAIN_CATALOG = DB_NAME()) AND
        (d.DOMAIN_SCHEMA = N'~~Schema.Name~~') AND
        (d.DOMAIN_NAME = N'Type~~TypeAndRule.Name~~')
)
BEGIN
    PRINT N'  ~~Schema.Name~~.Type~~TypeAndRule.Name~~, ~~Schema.Name~~.Rule~~TypeAndRule.Name~~';

    EXEC sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE TYPE ~~Schema.Name~~.Type~~TypeAndRule.Name~~ FROM ~~baseTypeDef~~ NOT NULL;';
    EXEC sp_addextendedproperty N'MS_Description', N'Encapsulates XXX.', N'SCHEMA', N'~~Schema.Name~~', N'TYPE', N'Type~~TypeAndRule.Name~~';

    EXEC sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE RULE ~~Schema.Name~~.Rule~~TypeAndRule.Name~~ AS (@value ~~atValueComparison~~);';
    EXEC sp_addextendedproperty N'MS_Description', N'Enforces XXX.', N'SCHEMA', N'~~Schema.Name~~', N'RULE', N'Rule~~TypeAndRule.Name~~';

    EXEC sp_bindrule @rulename = N'~~Schema.Name~~.Rule~~TypeAndRule.Name~~', @objname = N'~~Schema.Name~~.Type~~TypeAndRule.Name~~';
END;
GO
```

1. `TypeAndRule.Name` is the base name.
2. `Schema.Name` is the schema; e.g. dbo.
3. `baseTypeDef` is the underlying type definition; e.g. int, or nvarchar(50).
4. `atValueComparison` is the constraint expression.
5. The IF NOT EXISTS condition allows the script to run multiple times without errors.

The CREATE TYPE/RULE statements were originally deprecated in the SQL 2005 time frame and are still around. I doubt that they'll cause script errors any time before 2015 since MS have to maintain backward compatibility :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SQL CLR integration, with the idea that we store data with general types like (char, int), but then contextualize the data with constraints, specifically 'check' constraints.

Create a data type in a visual studio database project (C#) which internally stores the value as a primitive type (e.g. int, float, string, etc.), but constrains the values it can be constructed with.  For example, if you had a Score type, the constructor would throw an error if the value is outside the range of 0 to 100, ensuring that only valid Score objects can exist.

Your check constraint in the database table would simply involve calling a CLR function (which you would also create in your database project) that just tries to construct an instance of your C# data type with the new column value that you pass to it.  The function succeeds if the value is constructed, and fails if the constructor throws an error.

You then have a constrained data type, centralized in your C# code, usable throughout your application, which also enforces values in the database.

Comment: I've tested only the data-type classes, not query perf. with constraints on.  Consider that performance depends on data error rate (constructor throws error).  An acceptable performance delay then depends on your query rate (e.g. a 0.5s try/catch delay no big deal if 1 qps, but huge deal if 1000qps)

Answer (score -3):

Use a check constraint

example

```
create table bla (value varchar(50) 
default 'A' 
constraint CheckValue check (len(value) > 0))
go
insert bla default values
go
insert bla values('1')
go
insert bla values('') --will fail
go
```

Comment: I know how to put a check and a default value in a single column. But I want to create a TYPE.

Comment: Your original question did not say "I don't want to add a check constraint and a default value for every single column."

Comment: Your are right. I added because you didn't pay attention to the word "TYPE" that was in my original question. "..to create a TYPE...".

Comment: And it's a shame if you voted my question down just because you didn't pay attention to it and posted a wrong answer.

Comment: My answer answers the first sentence you posted "What's the recommended way to create a type in MSSQL 2005 with a default value and a check constraint to be used in several columns?" because types are deprecated, what else can you do? create a UDF? maybe perhaps but how is it easier than this?